# Connect to Office is not working on SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office

Hope you're well;

I am trying to connect my SharePoint site folder via Connect to Office. Nothing happening. I am using IE 11. How do I solve this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue. There are two user voices about this issue, you can vote them.
[Fix "Connect to Office"](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/282887-sharepoint-hybrid-or-migration-to-office365/suggestions/13701261-fix-connect-to-office)
[Getting back Connecting with Office](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/17375827-getting-back-connecting-with-office)

As a workaround, you can temporarily use **Recent Folders** of Save As.